# Initialize dictionary with KeyValuePair

Tags: c#

Within initialisation of a large object that contains many different types of child object...

I have a function that returns a `KeyValuePair<string, object>`. I would like to call this when initialising a `Dictionary<string, object>`, something like this:

```
AdditionalProperties = new Dictionary<string,object>(ams.GetKVP(AvaloqTypes.Person.PersonDocm.CountryId))
```

This gives a compilation error that *"cannot convert from KeyValuePair to IDictionary"*

I can work-around this as follows:

```
AdditionalProperties = new Dictionary<string,object>()
{
    { ams.GetKVP(AvaloqTypes.Person.PersonDocm.DocmItem).Key,
      ams.GetKVP(AvaloqTypes.Person.PersonDocm.DocmItem).Value 
    }
}
```

However, this means the `GetKVP` method is called twice.

Is there a better solution that doesn't involve changing the `GetKVP` method?

Comment: `Dictionary` doesn't have a constructor that takes a `KeyValuePair`, it's not clear why you thought that would work?

Comment: Why the C# 8 tag? There's nothing specific to C# 8 in the question

Comment: Since it's just a single pair why not use the dictionary initializer syntax?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos so that people know the version of c# I’m working with and offer possible solutions that may only be available in that version or higher

Comment: @RobBowman the library is provided by the runtime, not the language. Are you targeting .NET Core or the old framework? All of the answers that accept an `IEnumerable<KVP>` work since .NET Core 2.0. No constructor accepts a single KVP. The dictionary initializer works in all versions'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no constructor overloading for `Dictionary` which takes `IKeyValuePair` as an argument. But you can pass a collection of `KeyValuePair` when instantiating new `Dictionary`:

```
var kvp = new Dictionary<string,object>(new [] 
{ 
   ams.GetKVP(AvaloqTypes.Person.PersonDocm.CountryId)
});
```

EDIT: This constructor exists only in .NET Core

[link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.-ctor?view=netcore-2.2#System_Collections_Generic_Dictionary_2__ctor_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable_System_Collections_Generic_KeyValuePair__0__1___)

Comment: @DavidG because his method returns `KeyValuePair<string,object>`. If you have doubts please post more meaningful comment

Comment: @DavidG There's a `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>(IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue>>)` while the OP tried to pass a *single* instance. In this case a new list is constructed with that single instance

Comment: @OlegI you could have used an array instead of a list

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos There is? Could you show me which constructor? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos If you leave the C#8 reference in though, it does exist there. That should probably be specified.

Comment: @DavidG it was added [in .NET Core 2.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.-ctor?view=netcore-2.0#System_Collections_Generic_Dictionary_2__ctor_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable_System_Collections_Generic_KeyValuePair__0__1___) along with many other constructors so it's not specific to C# 8. It was never added to .NET Old though, not even in 4.8

Answer (score 5):

You can always just extract the kvp to a variable and use that, so the method won't be called twice.

```
var kvp = ams.GetKVP(AvaloqTypes.Person.PersonDocm.DocmItem);
AdditionalProperties = new Dictionary<string,object>() { { kvp.Key, kvp.Value } }
```

But I would question the choice of using kvp in this case or the dictionary if there is just one kvp?

Comment: Sorry I should have state that I need to do this in a larger initialisation block - so no option to declare variables

Answer (score 0):

Other options

```cs
AdditionalProperties = new Dictionary<string,object>(new List<KeyValuePair<string, object>> { ams.GetKVP(AvaloqTypes.Person.PersonDocm.DocmItem) });
```

Comment: This doesn't compile

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is a Add-Method you can use, which takes a KeyPairValue as a parameter.

The problem: It is a **explicit** implementation of the ICollection [Add](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.icollection-1.add?view=netframework-4.8)-Method.

That means you can only call it by casting your Dictionary to a ICollection or any interface that inherits ICollection and is implemented by Dictionary.

And there is a interface which does exactly that and exposes the functionality of the Dictionary-Type: [IDictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.idictionary-2?view=netframework-4.8)

So by defining `AdditionalProperties` as `IDictionary<string, object> AdditionalProperties` you can do:

```
AdditionalProperties = new Dictionary<string,object>();
AdditionalProperties.Add(ams.GetKVP(AvaloqTypes.Person.PersonDocm.DocmItem));
```